# VHDL Changing and holding the signal in if statement

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Im super new with VHDL and I have an assigned project to do. Basically what I'm aiming is to display 2 numbers and substract and add them with the help of a switch. (On FPGA Board)

For example:
Assume I have a signal A with the bit value 9 and B with 2, whenever I open the switch it will operate A-B and display 7. The problem is, when I close the switch, I get 9 instead of 7. (It doesn't hold the value) What I want is to display all the substraction results with opening and closing the same switch : 9,7,5,3,1

What I did so far:

1. I coded a decoder for the seven segment display
2. I have a 5 bit bitslice adder substractor implementation
3. In my main module, I have them as components and instantiations
4. In main module, I have signals for the two numbers which I declared
   as the input values of my bitslice instantiatons
5. In the process, I assigned the default values to my signals (9 and 2)
6. Inside of an if statement, I assigned the signal A to the result
   signal (which is assigned to adder-substractor instantiations bit by bit) And assigned the signal for seven segment to result.

It works when I open the switch, but when I close the switch default value holds. How can I update the value of A with the result each time?

My Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity main is

    Port ( 
              S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Cout: out STD_LOGIC;
              StartGameSwitch : IN std_logic;
              SevenSegControl : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):=x"ff";
              SevenSegBus : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
              clk : IN std_logic);
end main;


architecture Behavioral of main is

--COMPONENTS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

COMPONENT sevenSegment
    PORT(
        A : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        B : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        C : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        D : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        E : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        F : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        G : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        H : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        SevenSegControl : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        SevenSegBus : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        clk : IN std_logic          
        );
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT logic
    PORT(
        A : IN std_logic;
        B : IN std_logic;
        COld : IN std_logic;
        S : IN std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        AG : IN std_logic;
        BG : IN std_logic;          
        CNew : OUT std_logic;
        NumberBit : OUT std_logic;
        negativeSign : OUT std_logic
        );
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT comparator
    PORT(
        A : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        B : IN std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);          
        AG : OUT std_logic;
        BG : OUT std_logic
        );
END COMPONENT;

--SIGNALS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

signal sA,sB,sC,sD,sE,sF,sG,sH: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0) ;
signal logicLed,result,negativeSign,sevenSegmentResult,sevenSegmentNegativeSign: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
signal c0,c1,c2,c3,c4: std_logic;
signal AG,BG: std_logic;
signal HP1,HP2,ATK1,ATK2: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);

--CONSTANTS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

constant charO:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01010"; --10
constant charP:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01011"; --11
constant charE:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01100"; --12
constant charN:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01101"; --13
constant charF:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01110"; --14
constant charI:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01111"; --15
constant charG:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "10000"; --16
constant charH:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "10001"; --17
constant charT:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "10010"; --18
constant charA: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "10011";--19
constant char0:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00000";
constant char1:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00001";
constant char2:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00010";
constant char3:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00011";
constant char4:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00100";
constant char5:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00101";
constant char6:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00110";
constant char7:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00111";
constant char8:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01000";
constant char9:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "01001";
constant charEmpty:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "11111";

begin


--INSTANTIATIONS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Inst_logic1: logic PORT MAP(
        A =>HP2(0) ,
        B =>ATK1(0) ,
        COld =>c0 ,
        CNew =>c1,
        NumberBit =>result(0) ,
        S =>S, 
        AG => AG,
        BG => BG,
        negativeSign => negativeSign(0)
    );

        Inst_logic2: logic PORT MAP(
        A =>HP2(1) ,
        B =>ATK1(1) ,
        COld =>c1 ,
        CNew =>c2,
        NumberBit =>result(1) ,
        S =>S, 
        AG => AG,
        BG => BG,
        negativeSign => negativeSign(1)
    );

        Inst_logic3: logic PORT MAP(
        A =>HP2(2) ,
        B =>ATK1(2) ,
        COld =>c2 ,
        CNew =>c3,
        NumberBit =>result(2) ,
        S =>S, 
        AG => AG,
        BG => BG,
        negativeSign => negativeSign(2)
    );

        Inst_logic4: logic PORT MAP(
        A =>HP2(3) ,
        B =>ATK1(3) ,
        COld =>c3 ,
        CNew =>c4,
        NumberBit =>result(3) ,
        S =>S, 
        AG => AG,
        BG => BG,
        negativeSign => negativeSign(3)
    );

        Inst_logic5: logic PORT MAP(
        A =>HP2(4) ,
        B =>ATK1(4) ,
        COld =>c4 ,
        CNew =>Cout,
        NumberBit =>result(4) ,
        S =>S, 
        AG => AG,
        BG => BG,
        negativeSign => negativeSign(4)
    );  

        Inst_comparator: comparator PORT MAP(
        A => HP2,
        B => ATK1,
        AG => AG,
        BG => BG
    );

--GAME LOGIC-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



process(StartGameSwitch)
begin


--DEFAULT VALUES FOR HP1,HP2,ATK1,ATK2--
-- I WANT HP1 AND HP2 TO CHANGE ACCORDING TO SWITCHES --
    HP2 <= char9;
    ATK1 <= char2;   
   HP1 <= char9;
    ATK2 <= char3;

    if(StartGameSwitch = '0') then -- OPEN P35 ON FPGA

            sA <= charO; -- s_ are the signals for the seven segment 
            sB <= charP;
            sC <= charE;
            sD <= charN;
            sE <= charEmpty;
            sF <= charP;
            sG <= char7;
            sH <= char8;

    else -- WHEN P35 IS OPENED ( WHEN THE GAME STARTS) 


            sA <= HP1; --HP POINT FOR P1
            sB <= charEmpty; 
            sC <= ATK1; --Attack POINT FOR P1
            sD <= charEmpty; 

            sE <= charEmpty; 
            sF <= ATK2; --Attack POINT FOR P2
            sG <= charEmpty; 
            sH <= HP2; --HP POINT FOR P2

            if(S = "01") then -- WHEN PLAYER 1 ATTACKS PLAYER 2 ( HP2 - ATK1 = RESULT (i.e 9-2 = 7))
                HP2 <= result; 
                sH <= HP2; -- When SWITCH IS OPEN, IT SHOWS 7 WITHOUT ANY PROBLEM
            end if;
    -- HOWEVER, WHEN THE SWITCH IS AGAIN BACK TO 00, sH displays 9 instead of 7, HOW CAN I SAVE THE VALUE OF HP2?

    end if;
end process;

-- SIGNALS ASSIGNED TO DISPLAY 
Inst_sevenSegment: sevenSegment PORT MAP(
        A =>sA, --1ST PLAYER HEALTH 
        B =>sB, -- 1ST PLAYER DMG
        C =>sC ,
        D =>sD ,
        E =>sE ,
        F =>sF ,
        G =>sG , -- 2ND PLAYER DMG
        H =>sH , --2ND PLAYER HEALTH
        SevenSegControl =>SevenSegControl ,
        clk => clk,
        SevenSegBus => SevenSegBus
    );

end Behavioral;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your game logic process. Since your HP and ATK signals are in the top level of the process, they essentially get a continuous assignment to the default values all the time. The only time this changes is when you open the switch and you see the expected result displayed. When you close the switch again, the values get assigned their defaults again, rather than retaining the previous arithmetic result.

If you assign those signals their defaults only when you trigger `StartGameSwitch` (see below), then you should see the correct display when using your switch.

On a side note, your process sensitivity list was incomplete. The logic in your process depends on the switch signal `S`, so this should be included in the sensitivity list (as I've shown below). It doesn't really matter for synthesis, only for correctly simulating your code.

```
process(StartGameSwitch,S)
begin


--DEFAULT VALUES FOR HP1,HP2,ATK1,ATK2--
-- I WANT HP1 AND HP2 TO CHANGE ACCORDING TO SWITCHES --
    --HP2 <= char9;
    --ATK1 <= char2;   
    --HP1 <= char9;
    --ATK2 <= char3;

    if(StartGameSwitch = '0') then -- OPEN P35 ON FPGA

            HP2 <= char9;  --Assign default values here instead
            ATK1 <= char2;   
            HP1 <= char9;
            ATK2 <= char3;

            sA <= charO; -- s_ are the signals for the seven segment 
            sB <= charP;
            sC <= charE;
            sD <= charN;
            sE <= charEmpty;
            sF <= charP;
            sG <= char7;
            sH <= char8;

    else -- WHEN P35 IS OPENED ( WHEN THE GAME STARTS)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, the value stays the same now. Now I should move on to the next problem which is: I set the value of HP2 to something new, which is the result , and I want the new value of HP2 to decrease over and over again when I open and close the switch, so what I need is 9-2 = 7 and 7-2= 5 and so on. How do I implement that? i.e Is there a way of repeating the process with the new values?

Comment: Your current logic should already allow for this. Next time you toggle the switch, the next lower result should display.

Comment: Yes, it works if I toggle the switch when I only assign the result to sH (which is the display signal). If I assign the result to HP2, then I guess it continuously calculates the new result and displays nonsense values. How do I stop HP2 from changing continuously, but only change when I toggle the switch?

Comment: You could create a flag signal which only allows the update once (i.e. flag is initially set (update is allowed) / switch is moved to desired position / flag signal status is checked / if flag is set HP2 value is updated and flag signal is cleared (update no longer allowed), if flag is not set, do nothing / flag is reset when switch moves back to original position to allow update when switch moves back to the correct position)